# palindrome or not practice program using user input

Tags: python, palindrome

```
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]
def isPalindrome(string):
    temp=reverse(string)
    if temp==string:
        return True
    else:
        return False

string='tanmay' # input('enter a word')
ans=isPalindrome(string)
if ans==1:
    print' Yes palindrome'
else:
    print' no its not a palindrome'
```

if I ask for an input from the user the error what I got was Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Python27/prac06-2.py", line 10, in <module>
    string=input('enter a word')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
```

NameError: name 'tanmay' is not defined

but when I enter a string by myself the program is executed successfully

Comment: You should first make sure that the code you post here is the same as the code you run. Judging by your error messages, it isn't. `False` with an upper `F` is what you should be using.

Answer (score 1):

in python 2.7 `input()` evaluates the given input, you should use `raw_input()` to read in the data as a string. On another note, `temp==string` evaluates to a boolean so you do not need to put it in an if statement you can simply `return temp==string`

```
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]
def isPalindrome(string):
    temp=reverse(string)
    return temp==string

string=raw_input('enter a word')
if isPalindrome(string):
    print(' Yes palindrome')
else:
    print(' no its not a palindrome')
```

You can simplify `isPalindrome()` further by removing `reverse()` to:

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    return string == string[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a boolean `True` or `False` and you are trying to compare the result with a value `1`. Here is how you should invoke it.

```
ans = isPalindrome(string)
if ans: # you can also do (if ans == True)
    print 'Yes, it is a palindrome'
else:
    print 'No, it is not a palindrome'
```